# How do I create a Custom report for tracking more than one page in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to create a new custom report in Google Analytics for two pages. I do not need the entire site's traffic data. Just traffic received on two pages. The metrics I am trying to track are Page views, Unique Pageviews, Time on Site and Bounce Rate for those two pages.

Here's what I have done so far:

1. Went to Customization tab, clicked on New Report.
2. Added Page views, Unique pageviews, Bounce rate and Avg. time on site under Metric groups.
3. Dimension Drilldowns for Page (is this right?)
4. In Filters, I have added an Include > Page > Exact > URL of 1st page.

When I try adding another filter for second page like point 4, I see 0s when the report is generated. Have also tried adding the second page URL separated by the '|'. But, it still does not work. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Select the Flat table, add in the Page dimension, and add a regex filter to include only the page URLs you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

> In Filters, I have added an Include > Page > Exact > URL of 1st page.
>   ...
>   Have also tried adding the second page URL separated by the '|'. But, it still does not work.

For this to work, try switching to: Include > Page > RegEx > URL1|URL2